# Layout image and paragraph horizontally

Tags: html, css, accordion

I want to create a accordion with an image and paragraph.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <section id="accordion">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="check-1" name="acr" />
      <label for="check-1">Hardware</label>
      <article>
        <div>
          <img src="image/1.png">
          <h1>Processor</h1>
          <p>Choose the processor that best meets your performance needs. Your MacBook Pro comes as standard with the 2.5GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 processor. For even faster performance, configure your MacBook Pro with the 2.9GHz dual-core Intel Core i7
            processor.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
```

With the markup above, the image and paragraph are displayed vertically. I need to display them horizontally. How would I write the CSS for this?

Comment: Please mark the appropriate answer as accepted if it has fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just float right/left your image using CSS.

Example:

```
div#container section div article div img{
  float: left;  /* so that it moves to the left and the text is to the right */
  margin: 10px;  /* so that it looks nice */
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4neqpu00/1/)

[Here is a good tutorial about aligning images with text.](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/insert-images-website/align-float-images-css)

Comment: Your answer is correct. But why don't you make `.float-left{float: left;}` and add to that img tag? CSS class is for re-usability purpose. I would recommend to use css class (it is general).